# XCode 5 does not show full SVN history for repo

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode5

XCode 5.0.1 on OSX 10.9 does not show the full revision history for my repository under `Source Control/History`.

What it does display is the history up to a certain point several months ago, but nothing newer than that.

I tried viewing the repo and its history in Versions and there it works just fine.

At some point we migrated the repo from one server to another. We also upgraded the repository a while back, but I don't know to which version of SVN. However, I do know that we have Visual SVN Server and SVN 1.8.0 serverside.

On the other hand, the XCode 5.0 release notes state that XCode uses SVN 1.7, which leads me to suspect that this could be the cause of my issue. However, I also seem to remember that XCode used to refuse to work with unsupported versions of SVN.

Any ideas what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What sucks, but is the default in Xcode is that the server status is not automatically updated.

Open the preferences and go to the Source Control Preference and make sure the "Refresh server status automatically" button is checked.

There is nothing I can find within the Xcode UI besides this that tells you the server history is current or how to refresh it.

This is verified as of Xcode 5.1.1.  What a shitty UI.  Really.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

In my case sometimes begins work after "Source Control/Update".
Actually, its terrible bug, you have no guarantees that you see actual list!!!

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, it appears that there was something wrong with the working copy. Deleting it and then doing another checkout directly from XCode fixed the problem.

Yet another variation on 'turn it off, then on again'.

Comment: Though that worked for you, it's not actually correct.  Please see my other comment for the actual solution and why the problem happened in the first place.  Cheers.

Comment: @AlexZavatone I appreciate your answer and have upvoted it. I also accepted your answer, although obviously I can't verify it any more.