# Xcode 5 SVN comments not committed

Tags: svn, xcode5

I had developed a project using Xcode 4.x and had it in the SVN repository. I now migrated to Xcode 5 by checking out the repository and updating the SVN version upgrade pop-ups.

Now when I make changes in code and commit it, the code gets committed without errors. But when I try to view the history (or commit logs using command line) I can see the comments that date back to the last commit with Xcode 4.x. I can't see commit logs that have been committed with Xcode 5.

I need to know how do I get the comments updated along with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20217424)

> Deleting it and then doing another checkout directly from XCode fixed
>   the problem.